# Highcharts data labels not showing on multiple xAxis and yAxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using two `xAxis` and three `yAxis` in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hxLp6zkg/2/). As you can see the data labels for the two purple lines show as expected. But when you change the zoom level to anything more than 3m, the `dataLabels` hide.

I am using:

```
dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          allowOverlap: true,
          align: 'left',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          x: 0,
          y: -18,
          zIndex: 1000,
          crop: false,
          overflow: 'none',
          inside: true,
          padding: 0,
          maxPadding: 0,
          formatter: function() {
            return 'Other';
          }
        }
```

for one, and just `allowOverlap: true` for the other. None of them seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by dataGrouping, which group points when you set range above 3m. The solution is define formatter in plotOptions.series object, instead of point.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I only want `dataLabels` for one series or point? `plotOptions.series` uses the function for all of them.

Comment: Add the unique ID for point / series and add the condition in the global formatter, which checks ID. Then return value.